# where auto keyword can't determine the type in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Auto keyword is used to infer the type of the variable based on the initialization. But I read on internet that auto can't determine the type of the function parameters. I didn't understand the reason why auto can't determine the type when used with function parameters. Can any one please let me know why auto can't be used with function parameters and any other cases where auto keyword can't be used to determine the type.

Comment: `int f(auto x) { auto y = x + x; return 0; }` What type of `x` would you choose here if you were a compiler?

Comment: auto as function parameters would be the same as template. It is actually the case with lambdas.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: Why compiler will determine the type based on the usage inside the function definition when you will be passing arguments when you call the function? Why can't auto determine the type based on the parameters passed?

Comment: @kadina, because people have templates for that. It provides better control, and better all around in my opinion.

Comment: @kadina: the type isn't determined from usage, it's determined from initialization. `auto foo;` isn't valid however you use foo afterwards.

Comment: @Mat : Yes. I didn't understand the question posted by Silvio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Can't" is a strong word. After all, lambda parameters can use `auto` (in C++14). It's not so much "can't" as "doesn't". And perhaps "won't".

The question ultimately comes down to this: what does this actually do?

```
void foo(auto x)
{
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

`auto` deduction is ultimately based on providing an initializing expression, which is used to deduce the actual type. This declaration contains no initializing expression.

C++ is a statically typed language; that means the compiler must be able to determine the type of every expression and object *at compile time*. From just the above, the compiler can deduce nothing.

So how can the compiler know that `std::cout << x` is legal C++ syntax? It can only tell that if there is an `operator<<` overload that takes `std::cout` and `x`. It can't figure out what is being called without first knowing the type of `x`. Which it doesn't; it can be different for different invocations of the function.

However, there is one C++ construct where the above makes sense: a template. This is exactly what using `auto` in lambda parameters does; it implicitly transforms the function into a template function. So `[](auto x) {return x;}` effectively becomes an operator something like this:

```
template<typename T>
auto operator()(T x) {return x;}
```

However, this conversion doesn't just fall out of having `auto` as a deduction syntax. It has to be something the standard is explicitly written to require. And, with the exception of C++14 generic lambdas, it doesn't.

Concepts TS includes this facility. However, this is merely an extension of the ability to use concepts in function parameter lists at all. That is, they already have a way to make a function implicitly create a template function, so they just added `auto` as essentially a case of "a concept that accepts any type".

But this was explicitly *excluded* from the C++20 version of concepts. The general reason for this exclusion is that, up until this point, template functions could be detected because they always had to have some special syntax. Namely, the inducer `template<args>`. With the Concepts TS version, there is concern that people will write template functions without realizing it.

And template functions behave differently from non-template functions. A template function is a family of functions, so you can't get a pointer to the family itself. You'd have to explicitly instantiate the template to get a pointer to that particular function.

Comment: Note that the "accidental template" risk doesn't exist for lambdas. A lambda is an object, and objects can't be templates. ( They can contain templates, but you can still have a pointer to a lambda)